# tools to create SQL queries through a graphical interface

Tags: database, sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a tool other than Access that can create SQL queries, through a graphical interface.

This is what I'm trying to do

[image]

Adding some details, my database is on Postgres and I'm using the Access query builder with an `ODBC connection`.

I tried JetBrains and it does not seem to be able to do that, nor PGAdmin3 or PGAdmin4.

If you have any solutions other than Access, I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PgAdmin3, there is a graphical query builder (see the right tab on the upper left side of the animated gif)

[image]